# Excluding a directory with ISAPI-Rewrite

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, isapi-rewrite

I am trying to exclude a directory with ISAPI-Rewrite (note: this is a windows/iis port of mod-rewrite).

The directory I want to exclude is "api" when it is at the root of the site.

Here is my rule:

RewriteRule ^(/api/)(.+)$ $1$2 [NC, L]

A request would look something like this:
/api/v2/users?usernames=scottw

Unfortunately, the querstring value is always being excluded and the url is being rewrittten as /api/v2/users.

I am attacking under the assumption that (.+) would capture everything else.

Any suggestions? Or a better way to exclude a directory?

Thanks

**Update**: I have also simplified the rule, but that has not changed anything either:

RewriteRule ^(/api/.+)$ $1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there are two things going on here:

1. The regex should be ^(api/) and not ^(/api). The first "/" is excluded.
2. The regex parser tool which ships with ISAPI_Rewrite does not seem to handle querystrings properly.

The rule which finally appears to be working is:

```
RewriteRule ^(api/.+) $1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Turns out it can be even simpler. 

RewriteRule ^api/ - [NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

I've seen sometimes '.+' works oddly, you might try to switch to '..*' I'm not saying it will work, but it might be worth a try.